# Creating a custom CLI command for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, nuget

I was hoping to find a way to create a custom CLI command to perform a runtime task with the ASP.NET Core assembly. Pretty much the same way EF "Add-Migration" NuGet console command does it: I need to kickstart the server, initialize its services, run a specific method and then stop. The closest reference I could think of are Django's manage.py commands.

So I'm wondering if it's even possible to implement in a straight-forward way with no dark magic involved.

Thanks for any info provided!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement Django-like custom command is to create a Console Application inside your solution. Then add a reference to the ASP.NET project so you can use namespaces that are available from that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).